# How execute javascript at response from Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

At my Ajax response there is two variable: **js**, **html**.

The **js** variable contents Javascript in tag *script*: //Some code
And **html** contents HTML template.
How I can execute js code for html template from the successful response Ajax?

I tried this solution:

```
$('head').append(response.js); // not works
```

The full Ajax request:

```
getFormShare: function(type){
        var posting = $.post('/share/getFormShare', { type : type } );

        posting.done(function( response ) {
            response = $.parseJSON(response);

            $("head").append(response.js);
            $('.ShareBlock #block').html(response.html).show();

            initFileUpload(config);
            initEditor();

        });
    }
```

The PHP side:

```
$js = $this->listdata->WrapperJavaScript($specialization, array('name_field' => 'type[]', 'tab' =>'tab', 'div_element' => '.specMain', 'label' => 'Category', 'autosearch' => 'true'));

$html = $this->load->view('social/forms/video', $this->data, true);
echo json_encode(array('html' => $html, 'js' => $js)); die();
```

Comment: What does the JSON data look like?  I'm not a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and run your code after it loads:

```
 $.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

    alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script

 });
```

You can see a better explanation here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

---

Edit:
Since you're returning actual javascript and would like to execute it, you can simply do this in your ajax response:

```
 $.get(url,function(data){ $("body").append(data); });
```

Edit:
And with help from Mike's answer, you can use `eval()` to run the script if you don't have script tags in your response.  His answer gives more info on this.

Comment: Problem is that I have not a ready file js. It is generated by PHP and returned from Ajax. I need execute a some code js only.

Comment: The second your edit also is not good, I have a tag **<script>** in result  response, also in question I told that u tried: `$('head').append(response.js);`

Comment: Is the script or the file generated by PHP, the OP says one thing and you're saying another.

Comment: At response there is code: `<script>//SOME CODE</script>`

Comment: Then my 2nd edit should work.  And just to make sure you're not really using `response.js` as your variable, you can't use `.` in variable names.

Comment: Is there really a good reason to append the "script" tags into the HTML? You're bloating the DOM and you can already get the Javascript to be loaded into the page with eval. Seems like an exercise in superfluity...

Comment: @Alice You should post your ajax code, otherwise there's no way to really help.

Comment: @Mike thats how I do it, the original question seemed to ask otherwise.  I am unfamiliar with other methods, since this works fine.

Comment: Unless this is some page that gets saved offline, I don't see a good reason to append scripts into the DOM.

Comment: @Mike true, and I just +1 your answer because I will now use that. :)

Comment: @ZeeTee np mate, I've +1'd you because you at least are attempting to do what the question asked for, even if it might not be the best or most efficient method. She hasn't really given us much information about what she is trying to do, and I'm not sure why you would need to load scripts with AJAX unless these scripts are being generated by a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize javascript's eval to run string as code.

Keep in mind your string needs to be pure JS, no html or other elements to it.

example

```
eval("function foo() {console.log('bar');}");
//this call will create/instantiate a function called foo
```